# Android Studio hide incorrect "Probable bug"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

I've written the following equals function in class `Finding`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Integer)) {
        return super.equals(o);
    }
    return (o.equals(permanentID) || o.equals(tempID));
}
```

tempID and permanentID are both Integers. Now when I call finding.equals(5), I get a warning in my inspection:

> 'equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'Integer' and 'Finding' at line 55

I can choose to suppress this for the statement, member or class. But I actually want to suppress it for any call to this equals function. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is a side effect of the fact that your equals method is incorrect.  By the contract of `equals` on `Object` (the method you are overriding) it's not possible for an `Integer` to be equal to your `Finding` object.

**These are the rules for the equals method:**

1. It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x)
   should return true.
2. It is symmetric: for any non-null reference
   values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if
   y.equals(x) returns true.
3. It is transitive: for any non-null
   reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and
   y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true
   4.It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple
   invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently
   return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on
   the objects is modified
4. For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

You're better off creating a new method to do the comparison above, you're likely to get some strange results if you leave your `equals` method as it is.